# What is the underlying library/program to programs like less or top

Tags: terminal

Programs like `less`, `top`, `htop`, `git-log`, `man` and also editors like `vi`, `vim` or `nano` all open in this well known sort of "window" in the terminal, that is different from the typical prompt you normally work with.

**Example:**
When using `cat` it simply prints out the results onto stdout and shows you the prompt again.

On the other hand, when using `top` it goes into this separate "window" to display the information and even update it dynamically. Obviously it isn't a window as we understand it today, it just seems to be a visual trick where they overwrite the entire terminal screen repeatedly. Still, I think the analogy fits.

---

I was wondering, what is the underlying library or program that is used here? What is the proper name for such a "window"?

I do know about libraries like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which do similar stuff to what I am talking about, but I cant find any reference that for example `top` is using this library specifically. Also it looks quite differently from screenshots I have seen - might just be configuration.

Comment: These programs are designed to run on a terminal, either a real physical one like [VT52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT52), or a emulation of one like the Linux console ($TERM = linux) or Gnome / Xfce terminal ($TERM = xterm-256color) which use the [VTE Terminal Widget Library](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/VTE). Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: I don't think so. If I understand correctly this VTE library is used to build an actual terminal emulator but I am looking for something that allows to create "windows" inside the terminal itself. I tried to specify the question a bit more. I guess I am looking for something like ncurses. That might even be it, but from screenshots I have seen it looks rather different.

Comment: So are you asking about libraries/frameworks for building TUIs ([text-based user interfaces](text-based user interfaces)), but higher level than ncurses? Something like the good old [Turbo Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision) that was used by Turbo/Borland Pascal or the [Textual TUI framework for Python](https://github.com/willmcgugan/textual).

Comment: Ah yes, TUI seems to be exactly the words I have been looking for, thank you. You don't happen to know what framework specifically vim or top are using? Or is it custom built?

Comment: As far as I know [**top**](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/v3.3.17/top/top.c#L20) uses curses and nothing more, not even some custom internal library which could be extracted from the procps-ng project.